Puppeteer TimeoutError: Timed out after waiting 30000ms
I am trying to achieve a very simple pdf generation through Express JS, puppeteer and ejs.
I have used the following code on multiple occasions and have achieved similar results.
const router = require('express').Router();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const {_generateHtml} = require("./utils");

router.post('/offer-letter', async (req, res) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const html = await _generateHtml({
        doj: req.body.doj,
        name: req.body.name,
        role: req.body.role,
    }, 'offer-template.ejs');
    await page.setContent(html, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
    const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
        printBackground: true,
    });

    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.send(pdfBuffer);

});

module.exports = router;

Here's the generateHtml function as well
const {compile} = require("ejs");
const fs = require("fs");

async function _generateHtml(data, templatePath) {
    const template = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, 'utf8');
    let html = compile(template);
    return html(data);
}

module.exports = {
    _generateHtml
}

Here's the folder structure
.env
index.js
node_modules
offer-letter-template-html.html
offer-template.ejs
package-lock.json
package.json
pdfRoutes.js
utils

However, I now find myself with an error message that's quite the headscratcher. How exactly do you work out this one?
            throw new Errors_js_1.TimeoutError(`Timed out after waiting ${ms}ms`, { cause });
                  ^

TimeoutError: Timed out after waiting 30000ms
    at C:\work\offer-letter-manager\backend\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\util.js:289:19
    at C:\work\offer-letter-manager\backend\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\third_party\rxjs\rxjs.js:3986:35
    at OperatorSubscriber2._this._next (C:\work\offer-letter-manager\backend\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\third_party\rxjs\rxjs.js:1055:13)
    at Subscriber2.next (C:\work\offer-letter-manager\backend\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\third_party\rxjs\rxjs.js:678:16)
    at AsyncAction2.<anonymous> (C:\work\offer-letter-manager\backend\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\third_party\rxjs\rxjs.js:4863:24)
    at AsyncAction2._execute (C:\work\offer-letter-manager\backend\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\third_party\rxjs\rxjs.js:1974:16)
    at AsyncAction2.execute (C:\work\offer-letter-manager\backend\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\third_party\rxjs\rxjs.js:1963:26)
    at AsyncScheduler2.flush (C:\work\offer-letter-manager\backend\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\third_party\rxjs\rxjs.js:2235:30)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  [cause]: undefined
}

Node.js v20.12.1


Here's a sample of ejs file you can use
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="page-container">
    test
</div>


</body>
</html>

22nd May 2024 - Edit --------------------------------
This is the minimal failing code for everyone trying to replicate the issue.  
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function generatePDF() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, timeout:0});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent("<h1>Hello World</h1>", { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
  console.log("Content set");
  const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ printBackground: true });
  console.log("PDF generated");
  await browser.close();
}

generatePDF().catch(console.error);

package.json for the project
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^22.9.0"
  }
}


Never use timeout: 0. This suppresses useful errors and causes scripts to hang forever. Which line times out? The code here looks fine, more or less. Can you include a minimal version of offer-template.ejs so I can run the code and see the failure? I assume there's nothing significant there, and it's clearly not the cause of the hang, but the example should be complete and easily runnable. In fact, I'd remove EJS completely since it's almost certainly not part of the problem.

So far what I have debugged, the problem lies at page.pdf()
I get the same error even with using
await page.setContent(html); instead of
await page.setContent(html, {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});

Good to know, but that's still not enough info to reproduce this. Please respond to all parts of my comment above. You can [edit] your post to include the [mcve].

@ggorlen added the sample ejs file to the post now

Thanks but it's still not reproducible, as my answer shows.

I'm unable to reproduce your problem. Here's my code that works just fine on Node 20 and Ubuntu 22.04.
server.js:
// Note: error handling is not included. I don't recommend this setup;
// it's purely for reproduction and doesn't follow best practices.

const fs = require("fs");
const {compile} = require("ejs"); // ^3.1.10
const express = require("express"); // ^4.19.2
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.7.1

const app = express();

async function _generateHtml(data, templatePath) {
  const template = fs.readFileSync(templatePath, "utf8");
  const html = compile(template);
  return html(data);
}

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const html = await _generateHtml({}, "offer-template.ejs");
  await page.setContent(html);
  const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
    printBackground: true,
  });
  res.set("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
  res.send(pdfBuffer);

  // browser should be closed in a finally
  // block here if this were a real script.
});

app.listen(3000);

offer-template.ejs:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="page-container">
    test
</div>


</body>
</html>

Run node server, visit your browser at http://localhost:3000 and you'll see the PDF correctly rendered. Since the POST data isn't used in the template (and templating should be irrelevant as far as a hang is concerned--it ultimately returns a string, which you could hardcode for minimal reproducibility), I removed that. Same for the exported module--it's irrelevant.
Please provide more details and steps to reproduce the issue. There's nothing obviously wrong with the code you've shown, other than using timeout: 0, which stifles errors and can cause an infinite hang.

thanks for prompt answers man. I gotta hid the bed as I'm literally falling off my seat, given that it's 5am where I'm at, I'll give this a try first thing and grt back with a more reproducible code.

Sounds good. You might want to try running my code here in a clean environment and ensure it works for you though (please confirm one way or the other when you can). If this code doesn't work for you, then that's interesting--probably an environment detail of some sort.

Strangely, on using the exact code as you shared, I am still getting the same error.
I am running node 20 on windows 11 with ryzen 7840HS
Here's the package.json file
{   "name": "backend",   "version": "1.0.0",   "main": "index.js",   "scripts": {     "start": "node index.js",     "dev": "nodemon index.js"   },   "keywords": [],   "author": "",   "license": "ISC",   "description": "",   "dependencies": {     "cors": "^2.8.5",     "ejs": "^3.1.10",     "express": "^4.19.2",     "puppeteer": "^22.9.0"   },   "devDependencies": {     "nodemon": "^3.1.0"   } } 

Can you minimize the problem further? You should be able to update your post with only launching, creating a page and calling page.pdf() as a minimal reprex--remove the red herrings like EJS, Express and Nodemon that are probably unrelated to the problem. I'm not sure what the cause is, though, but it could be a bug in Puppeteer. Include your package.json file in the update, along with the complete, runnable minimal failing code.

If it is only happening on Windows and with Chrome 125+, it is probably this issue https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting#chrome-reports-sandbox-errors-on-windows (check with dumpio: true)

@ggorlen adding this seems to have made it work. args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
Thanks for your insights. I bared it down to a simple node script and then jumped into it from there.

Please update the post with your minimal failing code to help future visitors and post a self answer. I don't think disabling sandboxing is a good idea or solution, but glad you got it working.

Launching the puppeteer instance with disabling sandboxing worked for me as a workaround for now. I have to deploy the actual implementation of this in production sometime soon, so I will try to post a more suitable solution later.
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox']});


This one works for me, but I'm curious on what are the cons by implementing it.

Hey! This works for me too. But what could be the cons? Is there any other implementation?

The problem with sandbox is that it disables some security features in chrome and that can open a totally different can of worms. My code wasn't for production, so I wasn't worried about it at that point, but this is still an open issue on my end.

Im having this issue too. Its just suddenly stopped working one week
EDIT: As mentioned above, disabling sandbox is a workaround but more of a hack. The issue lies with permissions. If you run page.pdf({ dumpio: 'true' }) you will see the output of errors
FIX:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-reports-sandbox-errors-on-windows
You can try to fix this issue by manually setting the necessary permissions for the Chromium executable with the icacls command, as suggested in the error message. Open a command prompt as an administrator and run the following command:
icacls %USERPROFILE%/.cache/puppeteer/chrome /grant *S-1-15-2-1:(OI)(CI)(RX)
This command grants the necessary permissions to the Chromium executable that Puppeteer uses.

There could be several reasons for encountering this error. One common cause is the default timeout in Puppeteer, which is set to 30,000ms by default.
To address this, add proper logging to identify where the timeout occurs. Then, either pass a timeout value of 0 to disable the timeout entirely or set a relevant timeout duration based on your specific use case.
I also faced the same issue while generating a pdf from puppeteer, then I added
        const pdfPages = await page.pdf({
        timeout: 0 //or time taken for your process in ms (eg) 60000 
    });

It works for me

I'm using windows and I had the same problem, I tired icacls $env:USERPROFILE/.cache/puppeteer/chrome /grant *S-1-15-2-1:(OI)(CI)(RX) but it did not work for me. then I looked at this puppeteer folder, and found another folder named "chrome-headless-shell" so I ran; icacls $env:USERPROFILE/.cache/puppeteer/chrome-headless-shell /grant *S-1-15-2-2":(OI)(CI)(RX)", and now the pdf generation works.
